# Need help to read text present in the div element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**PFB snippet**

```
<div id='divId'>
<span></span>
here is the text
<span></span>
</div>
```

`driver.findElement(By.id("divId")).getText()` is not working. please suggest me a way to read this text in java code

Comment: If the particular text field comes after a page load or something like that, wait until the text portion comes visible and then use the `getText()` to read the text

Comment: '//div[@id='divId']/span' Try this

Answer (score 0):

The text is present in the `span` not in `div`. Therefore you should use xpath containing `span`.  Like here-
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22590/how-to-find-int-value-within-span-class-selenium-c/22604#22604

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

//div[@id='here is the text']

if it works then fine. else, open selenium IDE then click on "find" button drag mouse to the specific element where you want to locate then click on the element. now you are able to find different locator values in the target field.

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("divId")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("divId")).getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

if it doesn't return the specific text you can parse it from there